# How do I pass the resulting files from one grep pass to another so that I only grep through the subset with the second pass?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to be able to take the files I found with my first grep statement, something like this for example: 
    grep -r Makefile *
And then pass the files found in that pass of grep to a second grep with something like this for example:
    grep {files} '-lfoo'

How do I do this? I know there must be a way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -l firstmatch * | xargs grep secondmatch {}
```

Comment: I'd recommend: `grep -l firstmatch | xargs grep -- secondmatch`. This will cause grep to be invoked as few times as possible.  Also without the `-I {}` (or now deprecated -i) the braces won't be interpreted. Also, your command causes grep to be run for each file found by the first grep invocation and will grep for `{}` (or its substitution depending on your grep variant).

Comment: @NSA: `xargs` is a command.  It reads its standard input for a list of arguments (normally file names), and then concatenates them with the arguments of the command (in this case '`grep {} secondmatch`' to create commands that are executed.  For more information, RTFM.

Comment: I would recommend using `grep -lZ ... | xargs -0 ...` to protect against spaces in filenames.